# Using UISegmentedControl to save mapKit preferences with NSUserDefaults - not working correctly

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control with 3 options to save standard/satellite/hybrid maps in the NSUserDefaults. One problem I'm having is that the segmented control changes back to the first  segment whenever the mapSettingsViewController is re-visited. The other problem is that mapViewController doesn't reload on viewWillAppear.

I'm using a pageCurl modal transition with Storyboarding - not sure if that matters.

this is the code in settings view controller (mapSettingsViewController) to save the segmented selection:

```
    - (IBAction)changeMapType: (id)sender{


    NSInteger index = ((UISegmentedControl*)sender).selectedSegmentIndex;

    // Get the shared defaults object.
    NSUserDefaults *mapUserPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if(segmentedControlMapType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        // Save the index.
    [mapUserPreferences setInteger:index forKey:@"mapViewKey"];

    }
    else if(segmentedControlMapType.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        // Save the index.
        [mapUserPreferences setInteger:index forKey:@"mapViewKey"];
    }
    else if(segmentedControlMapType.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
        // Save the index.
        [mapUserPreferences setInteger:index forKey:@"mapViewKey"];

    }

    // Write them to disk
    [mapUserPreferences synchronize];
}
```

then in the first view controller (mapViewController) to display the change to the map base on which segment was chosen by the user. I put the code in viewWillAppear so the map is reloaded when the view appears each time.

```
    -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Get the settings and set the selected index.
    NSUserDefaults *mapUserPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([mapUserPreferences integerForKey:@"mapViewKey"] == 0) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    }
    if([mapUserPreferences integerForKey:@"mapViewKey"] == 1) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    }
    if([mapUserPreferences integerForKey:@"mapViewKey"] == 2) {
        mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
    }

}
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: I changed in IB the segmented control to be unselected and it works. however the map still doesn't load on viewWillAppear on the mapViewController. You have to leave the view then return and then it loads. I'm wondering if the page curl transition has something to do with the viewWillAppear not reloading the map...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check, when modalView (pageCurl) is dismissed simply add the delegate method to your pageCurl Controller:

```
viewWillDisappear:
```

Then add the map update logic there.

Comment: I'm sure that's a way to do it. I'll just have to research how it's done... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you do that:

```
if(segmentedControlMapType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
// Save the index.
[mapUserPreferences setInteger:index forKey:@"mapViewKey"];
```

in the IBAction you get the event from (id)sender.

why don't you just put:

```
if((UISegmentedControl*)sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
```

Maybe I am on the wrong track, but your talking with 2 different instance objects of a segmented control.

what is it?
    segmentedControlMapType

the same as sender?

Comment: ok, thanks. any idea how to get the mapViewController to reload when it's re-visited after the segmented setting is changed on the mapSettingsViewController? I thought it would be viewWillAppear.

Comment: yes they are. I checked with: NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]); I'm using a page curl transition in the Storyboard. If I go back to the mapViewController from the mapSettingsViewController (the page curl) there's no map change. If I leave the mapViewController view and then come back the map is changed correctly.

Comment: because viewWillAppear will not be called. Just act like I've written in a post below